# Compile Error in Delphi 10 Seattle on creating any new Android Service other than Local Service

Tags: android, delphi, service, delphi-10-seattle

Steps to create error in Delphi 10 Seattle.

Working:
Create Blank Multi Device Application.

Save to "Dir1" set to target Android.

Add New Project to "ProjectGroup1", Android Service, Local Service.

Click "Save All" put service in Dir2 with projectgroup saving to the parent of Dir1 and Dir2.

Right click on service project and build. It will build.

Add to Blank Application and build and deploy.

Do all the above steps but choose anything other than Local Service and I get the error when trying to right click and build the service project:

> [Exec Error] The command ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac" -d javaclasses -Xlint:deprecation -classpath "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-22\android.jar";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\fmx.jar" -bootclasspath "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-22\android.jar" -encoding UTF-8 -target 1.6 -g -source 1.6 .\Android\Debug\Project2.java .\Android\Debug\Project2ProxyInterface.java" exited with code 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you save the project and the main form into different folders?

Comment: @WarrenP I saved I put C:\temp\H\ for the main project and C:\temp\S\ for the service with the group file being saved in C:\temp\

Comment: What happens if you run that JAVAC compile command from a command prompt without the args. Does it run fine? Just "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac"

Comment: Yes. Running that command in the service directory gets the following error: .\Android\Debug\UnitSvc.java:22: error: variable libraryName is already defined
in class UnitSvc
    private String libraryName;
.\Android\Debug\UnitSvc.java:25: error: cannot reference libraryName before supe
rtype constructor has been called
        super(libraryName);
.\Android\Debug\UnitSvc.java:55: error: cannot assign a value to final variable
libraryName
        libraryName = getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/lib" + baseLibra
ryName + ".so";

Comment: .\Android\Debug\UnitSvc.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        libraryName = getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/lib" + baseLibraryName + ".so";
  symbol:   variable baseLibraryName
  location: class UnitSvc
4 errors

Comment: Looking at that Java file it does seem to be a bug as far how it is constructed.

Comment: Your host application must be compiled first. It must also have run at least once.

Comment: @nolaspeaker I tried what you said. Compiled and ran the host application before adding a Local Remote Service Project, saving it to a dir and clicking on it and building. Same error. Any ideas?

Comment: These things are not simple. I can't help you any more unless you find somewhere to put your complete project source so I can look at it myself.

Answer (score 3):

1) Install JDK 1.8

2) go to start - run - regedit 
and find :
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\PlatformSDKs\AndroidSDK24.3.3_32bit.sdk

3) replace all items with "jdk1.7.0_25" to "jdk1.8.0_60"